# Map Vs Array List in two dimensions

Tags: arrays, flutter, dictionary, dart

I must store 2 information, file name and source in my application.
But, I am wondering if it would be more efficient to use List or to go with map.

Please, can you advise here. I am trying to get something efficient, simple and fast.
Not sure which direction I should take. Based on the research I have done it seems very similar, but I would be more than happy to get your point of view.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar. If you are going with an array, I suggest dropping a comment to note the index of the list is the file name and which is the source. But for cleanness, use the map; make the file name is the key(make this simple if possible), and the source is the value. Hope this helped in your decision.

Comment: Thank you. I am planning to use loop. For i=0,i< array.lenght, i++
So I am not sure if an index is required.